# Cant format date using apps script how to change a string to a date

Tags: google-apps-script, number-formatting

I have a sheet with dates along the top. The dates are not all in the same format. I'm in Europe so they are dd/mm/yy normally or dd/mm/yyyy. I put this function into the apps script area

```
function dateChange() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var column = sheet.getRange("D1:Y1");
column.setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yy");
}
```

To make everything the same format but none of the values changed, still lots of things show as dd/mm/yyyy. I also tried just highlighting the row and selecting format - then making it dd/mm/yy - still no good.

Commenter below suggested that they might be strings, not dates. How can I test to see if a cells content is a string or a date? If it is a string like 31/03/21 or 31/03/2021 how can I change that into a date please?

Here is a link to a cut down version of the sheet where you can see the mixed "date" formats in the cells: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0DwwON-7u7Rsqu8tSLYCPfogKCmZBaQHise-vthHII/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried this function as well with the results shown in the comments:

```
function datestuff() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()

 for(i = 1; i < lastColumn; i++){
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, i); 
  var data = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(data) // results are 20/3/2021, 19/3/21 etc. a mixture of dd/mm/yyyy and dd/mm/yy
  dateValue = new Date(data)
  Logger.log(dateValue) // results are all Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 GMT-05:00 1969, Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 GMT-05:00 1969
 }
}
```

Comment: May be they're not dates.  They could be strings

Comment: I bet thats what it is.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a cell contains a numeric date or a text string that just looks like a date, use an `=isnumber()` formula.

If you are importing the data from a text file or similar to the spreadsheet, set the locale of the spreadsheet so that it matches the data through **File > Spreadsheet settings** and re-import all data. This should get the dates converted correctly.

If the spreadsheet is your only copy of the data, you can use a formula to convert the text string dates to numeric dates. To best get help with that, please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: What would that look like please? I struggle to understand what people write here quite often. Not used to it yet.

var data = sheet.getRange(x,y).getValue();

if(data = isNumber()( {Logger.log("its a number")}

or something else? I'm only at the start of my journey so an example of what you mean by "use an isNumber() formula" would be a great help and would probably help me understand other peoples answers on other questions too!

Comment: "Use an `=isnumber()` formula" means "go to the spreadsheet, click a cell and type `=isnumber(A1)` where `A1` is the cell you want to inspect. Then press the **Enter** key to see whether cell `A1` contains a numeric value or if it contains text.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't appear to be a simple way to do what I needed to do so I selected the row, formatted to number>plain text, find replaced /21 with /2021 then I ran the following function:

```
function datestuff() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn()

 for(i = 1; i = lastColumn; i++){
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, i); 
  var data = range.getValue();

  if(data != "") {
    Logger.log("Cell contents are: " + data) 
    var dataArray = data.split("/")
    Logger.log(dataArray)


    var dataDay = dataArray[0]
    Logger.log("Day part is " + dataDay)
    dataDay = parseInt(dataDay)
    var dataMonth = dataArray[1]
    Logger.log("month part is " + dataMonth)
    dataMonth = parseInt(dataMonth) - 1
    var dataYear = dataArray[2]
    Logger.log("year part is " + dataYear)
    dataYear = parseInt(dataYear)

    if(dataYear < 2000) {dataYear = dataYear + 2000}

    Logger.log("Day is: " + dataDay + " Month is: " + dataMonth + " Year is: " + dataYear)
    dateValue = new Date(dataYear, dataMonth, dataDay)
    Logger.log(dateValue)
    range.setValue(dateValue)
  }
 }
}
```

I'm still shocked there isn't a very simple way to say "is this formatted into a date? if no, do it!"

Comment: Heads up: you are using code like `parseInt(string)`. This will *not* give what you want for values like `08` or `09` when you are using the Rhino runtime. It should work with the V8 runtime, but the best practice is to always explicitly specify the radix as in `parseInt(string, 10)`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description).